# ASP.net pasar valores de onclick a otra pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

En la primer pagina aspx tengo 2 botones con dificultad para mi juego (normal y dificil)

```
<div class="modal-body">
          <asp:ImageButton id="normal" ImageUrl="~/images/flecha_atras.png" class="flechaAtras" onclick="normal_Click" runat="server"/>
            <asp:ImageButton id="dificil" ImageUrl="~/images/flecha_atras.png" class="flechaAtras" onclick="dificil_Click" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

Los 2 botones me redireccionan a otra pagina aspx

```
public void normal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Puzzle5.aspx");
    }

public void dificil_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Puzzle5.aspx");
    }
```

En esa 2da pagina aspx tengo el siguente `script`

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(
        game.load(
            'procrastination_color2', 
            2, 
            3,
            'mandala'
        ), 333);
});
```

En base a los valores 2 y 3, me arma una pagina con cantidad de piezas para puzzle.

Lo que quiero hacer es mandar de la primera pagina, segun que boton que se presione, valores diferentes.

Por ejemplo si en la primer pagina se clickea boton NORMAL, mando (2,3)
Si se clickea boton dificil, a la otra pagina aspx, dentro del script, quiero mandar valores (8,5)

No se como puedo hacer eso. Alguna idea gente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si entendí bien lo que deseas hacer, lo puedes hacer de dos formas. Según el botón que des clic, enviar concatenado a la Url el valor que deseas.

```
public void normal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string valor;

        Response.Redirect("Puzzle5.aspx?valor=" + valor);
    }

public void dificil_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string valor;
        Response.Redirect("Puzzle5.aspx?valor=" + valor);
    }
```

Y en el load, de la pantalla que abres, recibes el valor por medio de un request Page.Request();

Si lo deseas hacer con JavaScript el request se mantiene de la misma forma, y solo cambia como abres la página que deseas.

```
var ruta = "URL.aspx?valor=123434";
window.open(ruta, ruta, "status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no, fullscreen=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes")
```

No utilizo mucho C# así que ese código es muy mejorable, espero te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias raintrooper